# Sublime Text 2 JSP Syntax Highlighting Problems

Tags: jsp, syntax-highlighting, sublimetext2, sublimetext

I have some issues with the built in syntax highlighting for JSP pages in Sublime Text 2.

See the code after the white line on line 11/12: The HTML tag `<strong>` is displayed correctly here.

The code before this line is not correctly colored: The second JSP closing tag (`%>`) is in red, but should be in orange like the first one and the HTML tags inside are recognized as Java code I think, although the scopes (visible with `CTRL+SHIFT+ALT+P` as `text.html.jsp`) do not change.

[image: JSP Syntax Highlighting in Sublime Text 2 (Theme: "Monokai Soda", edited colors of JSP start/end tags]

If I do the same with `<?php` or `<?` starting and `?>` closing tags the problem does not exist, all colors seem to be right then.

Did anyone have the same problem? I made sure that the syntax is set to JavaServerPages (JSP).

I think the problem relates to these lines in [HTML.tmLanguage](https://github.com/trevormorse/sublimepackages/blob/master/HTML/HTML.tmLanguage) file (JSP scope is inside HTML scope):

```
<dict>
    <key>embedded-code</key>
    <dict>
        <key>patterns</key>
        <array>
            <dict>
                <key>include</key>
                <string>#ruby</string>
            </dict>
            <dict>
                <key>include</key>
                <string>#php</string>
            </dict>
            <!--
            <dict>
                <key>include</key>
                <string>#smarty</string>
            </dict>
            -->
            <dict>
                <key>include</key>
                <string>#python</string>
            </dict>
        </array>
    </dict>
```

There is no include for JSP. But I'm only guessing... Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to edit the `HTML.tmLanguage` and `Java Server Pages (JSP).tmLanguage` files now... some matches for ruby overwrote the jsp scopes inside HTML `<script>` tags and I removed the match for curly brackets, and additionally I added some `text.html.jsp` includes to a few scope definitions.

---

I copied my `.tmTheme` file and put it into the `User` package folder as `User.tmTheme`. I then added these lines to this file at the bottom:

```
    <dict>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>Embedded Code Punctuation</string>
        <key>scope</key>
        <string>punctuation.section.embedded</string>
        <key>settings</key>
        <dict>
            <key>fontStyle</key>
            <string>bold</string>
            <key>foreground</key>
            <string>#FD971F</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>Embedded Java Code Directive</string>
        <key>scope</key>
        <string>punctuation.section.directive</string>
        <key>settings</key>
        <dict>
            <key>foreground</key>
            <string>#FD971F</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>Embedded Java Code</string>
        <key>scope</key>
        <string>source.java.embedded.html</string>
        <key>settings</key>
        <dict>
            <key>foreground</key>
            <string>#F8F8F2</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>Embedded Java Code String</string>
        <key>scope</key>
        <string>string.quoted.double.java</string>
        <key>settings</key>
        <dict>
            <key>foreground</key>
            <string>#E6DB74</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
```

I then edited these two files in the folders `HTML` and `Java` and commented out some ruby includes and stuff.

See the files here:

[HTML.tmLanguage](https://gist.github.com/dsine-de/dab215c468d32dd5ee5d)
[Java Server Pages (JSP).tmLanguage](https://gist.github.com/dsine-de/3718a5d013a5d2dc4dff)
[JavaScript.tmLanguage](https://gist.github.com/dsine-de/e888aa3c959993c690ab)

Comment: What changes did you make? Can you share? I'm having the same problem with JSP highlighting as well.

Comment: Can we get a fixed link on this please?

Comment: Hello, thanks for sharing @dennis ! I'm having the same problem but I don't see how to apply your fix, *where* do you put the updated *.tmLanguage files ? and I'm a little confused with the User.tmTheme as I have the impression you edited your answer several times... do we still need this User.tmTheme file ?

Comment: The *.tmLanguage files are here on my Mac: `/Users/USERNAME/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/[ HTML | Java | Javascript ]/`

Comment: Kinda late to the party but, is there a way to fix this in ST3? I couldn't find those files.